# Error locationManager.getLastKnownLocation

Tags: android, haversine

i follow tutorial about haversine formula

here is my function lokasi() in MainAcitvity

```
 private void lokasi(){
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    // permintaan update lokasi device dalam waktu 10 detik
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 1, this);

    if(location!=null){
        onLocationChanged(location);
        callListVolley(latitude, longitude);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Lokasi device pengguna tidak ditemukan.\nMohon hidupkan GPS.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        callListVolley(-6.894796, 110.638413);
    }
}
```

so when i run and then this error appear

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.example.invader.haversine, PID: 5913
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid provider: null
                                                                             at android.location.LocationManager.checkProvider(LocationManager.java:1704)
                                                                             at android.location.LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.java:1194)
                                                                             **at com.example.invader.haversine.MainActivity.lokasi(MainActivity.java:84)
                                                                             at com.example.invader.haversine.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:36)
                                                                             at com.example.invader.haversine.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:73)**
```

so when i check in logcat the error was in beginning of function but i dont know what should i do

Comment: what is inside locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); provider variable?

Comment: yes it is String variable

Comment: of course , but what value are you put inside?

Comment: it is just String provider; no value at all. so should i put any value on it?

Comment: See my answer. If you have others doubts add comment there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should check permission **before** request location.
Secondly you should check if provider exist and if it's enabled like this.

```
if(locationManager.getAllProviders().contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
   provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
}
```

for example if you want to use GPS_PROVIDER

Comment: yes it's work, but now the app load for a couple minutes and still didnt show up, should i change the emulator?

Comment: MainActivity is too lazy? at start up?

Comment: it's just rolling and rolling, nothing show up, i'll try with genymotion, i think that because my android emulator can't get location

Comment: try it with real device. So also with Genymotion have you same problem?

Comment: i think it was my computer,